# How can I create a column layout like this using css?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to display all my Departments, sub departments, brands like below in a sitemap page. How can I achieve this ?

I already tried with `column-count:3` using css. But it is not displaying contents in all the three columns. I want to display all the contents in maximum 3 columns and the contents are dynamic. How can I achieve this layout ?

[image]

This is my
**HTML**

```
<div class="sitemap-dept-panel">
    <div class="sitemap-dept-title"><span class="sitemap-dept-name">Electronics</span></div>
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-panel">
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
            <div class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Samsung</li>
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Motorola</li>
                <li>Lava</li>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
            <div class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Case</li>
                <li>Screen Guard</li>
                <li>Headphones</li>
                <li>Cables</li>
                <li>Powerbanks</li>
                <li>Charger</li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I found this one almost same as that of my requirement** [Walmart.com all department page](https://www.walmart.com/all-departments).

Comment: please provide html code.

Comment: @PawanLakhara HTML updated

Comment: Try this http://codepen.io/Cheesetoast/pen/KFAaq

Comment: Does your items flow from left to right or top to bottom?

Comment: @LGSon It can be in either ways. but the height of each column must be same.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I believe `flexbox` will let you control of how to lay out your content in the best way

```css
.sitemap-sub-dept-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.sitemap-sub-dept {
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.sitemap-brands-list-panel {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sitemap-dept-panel">
    <div class="sitemap-dept-title"><span class="sitemap-dept-name">Electronics</span></div>
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-panel">
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Samsung</li>
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Motorola</li>
                <li>Lava</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Case</li>
                <li>Screen Guard</li>
                <li>Headphones</li>
                <li>Cables</li>
                <li>Powerbanks</li>
                <li>Charger</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Samsung</li>
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Motorola</li>
                <li>Lava</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Case</li>
                <li>Screen Guard</li>
                <li>Headphones</li>
                <li>Cables</li>
                <li>Powerbanks</li>
                <li>Charger</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Samsung</li>
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Motorola</li>
                <li>Lava</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Case</li>
                <li>Screen Guard</li>
                <li>Headphones</li>
                <li>Cables</li>
                <li>Powerbanks</li>
                <li>Charger</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Samsung</li>
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Motorola</li>
                <li>Lava</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Case</li>
                <li>Screen Guard</li>
                <li>Headphones</li>
                <li>Cables</li>
                <li>Powerbanks</li>
                <li>Charger</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Samsung</li>
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Motorola</li>
                <li>Lava</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Case</li>
                <li>Screen Guard</li>
                <li>Headphones</li>
                <li>Cables</li>
                <li>Powerbanks</li>
                <li>Charger</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Samsung</li>
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Motorola</li>
                <li>Lava</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
            <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
            <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
                <li>Case</li>
                <li>Screen Guard</li>
                <li>Headphones</li>
                <li>Cables</li>
                <li>Powerbanks</li>
                <li>Charger</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Based on a comment, here is how one can do using `column-count`

```css
.sitemap-dept-name {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.sitemap-sub-dept-panel {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3;  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;
}
.sitemap-sub-dept-title {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 20px
}
.sitemap-brands-item {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 12px ;
}
```

```html
<div class="sitemap-dept-panel">
  <div class="sitemap-dept-title">
    <span class="sitemap-dept-name">Electronics</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-panel">
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Samsung</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Apple</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Motorola</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Lava</div>

    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Case</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Screen Guard</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Headphones</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Cables</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Powerbanks</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Charger</div>
    
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Samsung</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Apple</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Motorola</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Lava</div>

    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Case</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Screen Guard</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Headphones</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Cables</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Powerbanks</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Charger</div>
    
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Samsung</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Apple</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Motorola</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Lava</div>

    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Case</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Screen Guard</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Headphones</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Cables</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Powerbanks</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Charger</div>
    
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Samsung</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Apple</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Motorola</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Lava</div>

    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Case</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Screen Guard</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Headphones</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Cables</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Powerbanks</div>
    <div class="sitemap-brands-item">Charger</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this solution is not working as expected. Here each sub departments taking a fixed height (or look like so). I want that white space to be filled. Eg. https://www.walmart.com/all-departments#electronics---office

Comment: @SarathSNair With the existing markup you will not be able to accomplish that, you have to break it out as a sibling structure and then use `column-count`, since `flexbox` is not make for this.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by a siblings structure. How can I convert the above markup to siblings format ?

Comment: @SarathSNair Check this fiddle, does it help you out? .. https://jsfiddle.net/582jp2z4/1/

Comment: @SarathSNair  Updated my answer with the same code I used in the fiddle sample

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sitemap-dept-panel {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.sitemap-dept-title {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.sitemap-sub-dept-panel {
  max-height: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.sitemap-sub-dept-title {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sitemap-dept-panel">
  <div class="sitemap-dept-title">
    <span class="sitemap-dept-name">Electronics</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-panel">
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
      <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
      <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
        <li>Samsung</li>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Motorola</li>
        <li>Lava</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
      <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
      <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
        <li>Case</li>
        <li>Screen Guard</li>
        <li>Headphones</li>
        <li>Cables</li>
        <li>Headphones</li>
        <li>Cables</li>
        <li>Powerbanks</li>
        <li>Charger</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
      <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
      <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
        <li>Samsung</li>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Motorola</li>
        <li>Lava</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
      <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
      <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
        <li>Case</li>
        <li>Screen Guard</li>
        <li>Headphones</li>
        <li>Cables</li>
        <li>Powerbanks</li>
        <li>Charger</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
      <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
      <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
        <li>Samsung</li>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Motorola</li>
        <li>Lava</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
      <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
      <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
        <li>Case</li>
        <li>Screen Guard</li>
        <li>Headphones</li>
        <li>Cables</li>
        <li>Powerbanks</li>
        <li>Charger</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
      <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Mobile</div>
      <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
        <li>Samsung</li>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Motorola</li>
        <li>Lava</li>
        <li>Lava</li>
        <li>Lava</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sitemap-sub-dept">
      <div class="sitemap-sub-dept-title">Accessories</div>
      <ul class="sitemap-brands-list-panel">
        <li>Case</li>
        <li>Screen Guard</li>
        <li>Headphones</li>
        <li>Cables</li>
        <li>Powerbanks</li>
        <li>Charger</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Flexbox with column layout and allowed wrapping should work. You only have to specify the height.